# Execute python script from laravel

Tags: laravel, process

I should execute a script in python from a view in Laravel after pressing a button. In the controller I put the code to execute the script and that is:

```
public function scan()
    {
        $process = new Process(['C:\Simone\University\Smart IoT Devices\Lab_Raspy\Bluetooth', 'prova.py']);
        $process->run();
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) { throw new ProcessFailedException($process); }
        return redirect()->route('device');
    }
```

but when I press the button in the view I get this error:

> The command "'C:\Simone\University\Smart IoT
> Devices\Lab_Raspy\Bluetooth' 'prova.py'" failed. Exit Code: 127(Command
> not found) Working directory: /var/www/html/public Output:
> ================ Error Output: ================ sh: 1: exec: C:\Simone\University\Smart IoT Devices\Lab_Raspy\Bluetooth: not found

The view is set as follows:

```
@extends('backend.layouts.app')

@section('content')

<form action="{{ url('admin/scan') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-ghost-primary" id="scanner">Scan Device</button><br><br>
</form>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">USERNAME</th>
      <th scope="col">MAC ADDRESS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($data as $item)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{$item->id}}</th>
        <td>{{$item->USERNAME}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->MAC_ADDR}}</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/admin/singleDevice/{{ $item->id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Select</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
@endsection
```

**UPDATE**
I also tryied with the command

```
$process = shell_exec('python C:\Simone\Università\Smart IoT Devices\Lab_Raspy\Bluetooth\prova.py 2>&1');
        
return redirect()->route('backend.auth.user.device');
```

And the error change in:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException Route
> [backend.auth.user.device] not defined.

And my route is:

```
Route::get('device' ,[DeviceController::class, 'index'])->name('devices');
    Route::get('dict', [DeviceController::class, 'visualizeData'])->name('dict');
    Route::get('singleDevice/{device}', [DeviceController::class, 'singleDev'])->name('singleDev');
    Route::get('scan', [DeviceController::class, 'scan'])->name('scan');
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just a simple

$command = 'python C:\Simone\Università\Smart IoT Devices\Lab_Raspy\Bluetooth\prova.py 2>&1';

exec($command, $output);